# what does the number aside the mesh symbol mean?

Tags: outliner

[image]

what does the number (2,3,4) in the outliner aside the mesh symbol mean?

Comment: i think it's children. if you parent an object to another object with `Ctrl`+`P`, it will increment

Comment: you are right - i just found out too :D

Comment: I think it's the price in dollars, you owe 19$

Comment: Thank you moonboots - you are just the best Blender expert I know‼️‼️‼️‼️